# Dojo fails upon use of javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a dojo `scrollablePane` in my app which functions fine when the app first loads. However, my html file has an `onclick` function which triggers a JavaScript function which eventually calls `document.getElementId('').innerHTML = ''`, and once this executes, the correct data loads into the `scrollablePane`, but I can no longer scroll. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd really appreciate feedback on my answer, and whether or not it was able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change `innerHTML` you're destroying the elements in the DOM, so any handlers DOJO or anyone else put on them will be removed.

What about updating their content instead of using `.innerHTML=''` to destroy it? you can select the elements and update their text content.

Also, I suggest against `onclick="value"` as a way of attaching events, if someone else changed onclick, your method gets overridden, you can use addEventListener (and shim for attachEvent if you support old IE).

Comment: Sorry about that. I looked through the documentation after your comment and it looks like it suggests using the html.set() method, though it does say that .innerHTML='' should function as well...